# Powershell - Use "Set-UnifiedGroup" to change more Groups

Tags: powershell

)

I wanna set hundred of Groups unvisible in the GAL. Is there a option to do this easy and fast? I am beginner in PowerShell ;) so keep care 
Code is:

```
Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity "GroupName" -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true
```

It is way to much to do this with all groups. Does anybody know another way?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through all groups. First you need to get all groups. You can pass the return values to another Cmdlet with a pipe `|`.
There is a foreach-object loop. This means it will do something for every object returned by `Get-UnifiedGroup` or any other Cmdlet that returns objects

It should be something like that:

```
Get-UnifiedGroup | Foreach-Object { 
    Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity $_.Name -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true
}
```

As I'm not able to test this be sure the property is `$_.Name`.
If you just use `Get-UnifiedGroup` you can see the properties name in the headline

Comment: You should also be able to use the pipe inside the ForEach-Object if you are not sure about the `$_.Name`. Something like `$_ | Set-UnifiedGroup -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true`